# Obtain a std::ostream either from std::cout or std::ofstream(file)

Tags: c++, exception, iostream

how do I bind a `std::ostream` to either `std::cout` or to an `std::ofstream` object, depending on a certain program condition? Although this invalid for many reasons, I would like to achieve something that is semantically equivalent to the following:

```
std::ostream out = condition ? &std::cout : std::ofstream(filename);
```

I've seen some examples that are not exception-safe, such as one from http://www2.roguewave.com/support/docs/sourcepro/edition9/html/stdlibug/34-2.html:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::ostream* fp;                                           //1
  if (argc > 1)
     fp = new std::ofstream(argv[1]);                         //2
  else
     fp = &std::cout                                          //3

  *fp << "Hello world!" << std::endl;                         //4
  if (fp!=&std::cout) 
     delete fp;
}
```

Does anyone know a better, exception-safe solution?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
std::streambuf * buf;
std::ofstream of;

if(!condition) {
    of.open("file.txt");
    buf = of.rdbuf();
} else {
    buf = std::cout.rdbuf();
}

std::ostream out(buf);
```

That associates the underlying streambuf of either cout or the output file stream to out. After that you can write to "out" and it will end up in the right destination. If you just want that everything going to `std::cout` goes into a file, you can aswell do

```
std::ofstream file("file.txt");
std::streambuf * old = std::cout.rdbuf(file.rdbuf());
// do here output to std::cout
std::cout.rdbuf(old); // restore
```

This second method has the drawback that it's not exception safe. You possibly want to write a class that does this using RAII:

```
struct opiped {
    opiped(std::streambuf * buf, std::ostream & os)
    :os(os), old_buf(os.rdbuf(buf)) { }
    ~opiped() { os.rdbuf(old_buf); }

    std::ostream& os;
    std::streambuf * old_buf;
};

int main() {
    // or: std::filebuf of; 
    //     of.open("file.txt", std::ios_base::out);
    std::ofstream of("file.txt");
    {
        // or: opiped raii(&of, std::cout);
        opiped raii(of.rdbuf(), std::cout);
        std::cout << "going into file" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "going on screen" << std::endl;
}
```

Now, whatever happens, std::cout is in clean state.

Comment: Ooh, I like std::streambuf* better than std::ostream*

Comment: but if something throws, you will be left with a dangling pointer in cout of your streambuf* of the now destroyed ofstream. so beware, better write a RAII method.

Comment: I don't like hijacking std::cout.  It means that cout and printf are no longer equivalent, which is something that I imagine a lot of developers take for granted.

Comment: Can I somehow use this approach also if `out` is a member of class?

Comment: How to close the file currently associated with the object in first case `of.open("file.txt");`?

Answer (score 28):

This is exception-safe:

```
void process(std::ostream &os);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::ostream* fp = &cout;
    std::ofstream fout;
    if (argc > 1) {
        fout.open(argv[1]);
        fp = &fout;
    }
    process(*fp);
}
```

---

Edit: Herb Sutter has addressed this in the article [Switching Streams (Guru of the Week)](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/048.htm).

Comment: This doesn't seem any more exception-safe than the original code.

Comment: Yes it is.  The original code has a memory leak if an exception is thrown while processing (*fp << "Hello World" << std::endl).

Comment: Why this answer gets my vote is that the first answer breaks an old rule of mine "Don't mess with the internals of other objects". Just because you **can** replace rdbuf does not mean you should.

Comment: Herb's code, using the `?:` operator with 2nd and 3rd arguments of different types and lvalue/rvalue-ness, is not valid and does not compile with modern compilers such as Comeau Online or MSVC 10.0. I've mailed him about it. But until it's fixed, perhaps make a note of that in the answer, that the linked-to GOTW code is invalid. Cheers,

Answer (score 8):

```
std::ofstream of;
std::ostream& out = condition ? std::cout : of.open(filename);
```

Comment: How can it compile? The return type of `std::ofstream::open` is `void`.

Answer (score 3):

Referencing from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159452/c-assign-cin-to-an-ifstream-variable).

You can apply a similar approach.

```
struct noop {
    void operator()(...) const {}
};
```

```
std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> of;
if (condition) {
    of.reset(new std::ofstream(filename, std::ofstream::out));
} else {
    of.reset(&std::cout, noop());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Being a novice to C++, I don't know if this is exception-safe, but here's how I usually do it:

```
std::ostream& output = (condition)?*(new std::ofstream(filename)):std::cout;
```

Comment: Never use raw `new`, especially not like this.

Answer (score -4):

The following simple code works for me:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){   

    std::ofstream outF;
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        outF = std::ofstream(argv[1], std::ofstream::out); 
    }

    std::ostream& os = (argc > 1)? outF : std::cout;
}
```