# C++: assign cin to an ifstream variable?

Tags: c++, iostream, ifstream

You know the common stdio idiom that `stdin` is specified by
a filename of "-", e.g.

```
if ((strcmp(fname, "-"))
    fp = fopen(fname);
else
    fp = stdin;
```

What's the best way to do this with an `ifstream` instance?  I've received
a bit of code that has an `ifstream` as part of a class and I'd
like to add code to do the equivalent, something like:

```
if ( filename == "-")
    logstream = cin;  // **how do I do this*?*
else
    logstream.open( filename.c_str() );
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`cin` is not an `ifstream`, but if you can use `istream` instead, then you're in to win. Otherwise, if you're prepared to be non-portable, just open `/dev/stdin` or `/dev/fd/0` or whatever. :-)

---

If you *do* want to be portable, and can make your program use `istream`, here's one way to do it:

```
struct noop {
    void operator()(...) const {}
};

// ...

shared_ptr<istream> input;
if (filename == "-")
    input.reset(&cin, noop());
else
    input.reset(new ifstream(filename.c_str()));
```

The `noop` is to specify a deleter that does nothing in the `cin` case, because, well, `cin` is not meant to be deleted.

Comment: thanks... this only needs to be portable to linux and osx, so /dev/stdin it is! (sigh)

Comment: this illustrates how no one ever sat down and made a halfway decent set of c++ libs.   (i would say boost if it didn't have so many versioning issues)

Comment: FWIW, with C++11 instead of passing `noop()` to `reset` (and defining the struct), a simple (and funny looking) `[](...){}` does it.

Comment: @akim Yep. Go lambdas!

Answer (score 0):

- Save the initial [streambuf of cin](http://dinkumware.com/manuals/?manual=compleat&page=ios.html#basic_ios::rdbuf) into a variable
- Change the [streambuf of cin](http://dinkumware.com/manuals/?manual=compleat&page=ios.html#basic_ios::rdbuf) to the [one from the file](http://dinkumware.com/manuals/?manual=compleat&page=fstream.html#basic_fstream::rdbuf).
- Do what you need to do
- And don't forget to restore cin streambuf before closing your file -- RAII may help.

Comment: I wrote a very similar answer an hour ago, but then deleted it after re-reading this part of the question: "I've received a bit of code that has an ifstream as part of a class". The question's title is misleading in that it may be read as "how do I redirect cin to read from a file", but it is, IIUC, the reverse: The OP already has an ifstream and would like to redirect it to cin.

Comment: Indeed. We cannot change the streambuf of an ifstream like that.
As in Chris Jester-Young's solution, the exact type of the stream used needs to be changed.