# Are shared_ptr on static objects good?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, static, smart-pointers

I'm wondering whether smart pointers on static objects are reasonable. For example let's say I have some static resource and want to pass a reference to that static resource to some other objects which need these resource to work with.

One way would be to use the RAW-Pointers pointing to that resource. But now I'm wondering whether smart pointers (shared_ptr) are the better way and if so, how to do it correctly. (should the smart pointer be static as well?).

Background of the question: if no more objects holding a smart pointer anymore, the static object which the smart pointer is point to, would be freed (which is not the best idea...).

One example (which ends in a crash at the end of runtime):

```
struct SomeType {
  SomeType() { cout << "ctor..." << endl; }
  ~SomeType() { cout << "dtor..." << endl; }

  void sayHello() { cout << "Hello!" << endl; }
};


void someFunction(shared_ptr<SomeType> smartPointer) {
  smartPointer->sayHello();
}

static SomeType st;
static shared_ptr<SomeType> pt{ &st };

void anotherFunction() {

  someFunction(pt);
}

int main() {
  anotherFunction();

  cin.get();

}
```

Comment: There is no need for shared_ptr here whatsoever.

Comment: smart pointers are for better management of *dynamic* lifetimes. Static variables already have a *static* lifetime.

Comment: "One way would be to use the RAW-Pointers pointing to that resource" The obvious thing to do is to use a reference to the resource. Why would you not want to do that?

Comment: Ok let's assume that I (as the class author) don't know whether the object is static or dynamic. I just need a pointer to an object with the interface   `IDoSomething`.

Comment: @Andreas: " I just need a pointer to an object with the interface IDoSomething" Sounds like you already know the answer then.

Comment: Smart pointers are used to convey ownership.  If the functions will not participate in the ownership then you can use a raw pointer.  If they do but only want a way to check and see if they still have a valid reference then I would suggest a `weak_ptr`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: but when you use a weak pointer you still need a dynamically allocated object. Thus I don't believe that this is what andreas mentioned. For static objects either a raw pointer or a reference could be used

Comment: @Chris No you do not.  You can construct a `shared_ptr` from an automatic object.  You just need to get the deleter right, as in, have it do nothing.

Comment: @NathanOliver You can but it is usually a bad idea and the sign of a problem. Owning smart pointers (shared or not) manage a resource; if you don't want to manage a resource, and esp. if you **cannot** manage it, then you probably should not make a smart pointer to it.

Answer (score 11):

The following two lines are not valid.

```
static SomeType st;
static shared_ptr<SomeType> pt{ &st };
```

When `pt` is destroyed at the end of your process' lifetime, it will `delete st`. `st` was never allocated with a matching `new`. This is undefined behavior.

`shared_ptr` is useful for managing the complex lifetime of shared objects while `static` objects have very simple lifetimes. It is incorrect to use `shared_ptr` to manage `static` objects and there would be nothing to gain in doing so.

Comment: It's not incorrect to use `shared_ptr`, it's incorrect to use `shared_ptr` with the default deleter.

Comment: "_static objects have very simple lifetimes_" Namespace scope static of function scope static?

Answer (score 6):

> let's assume that I (as the class author) don't know whether the object is static or dynamic

Code that needs to be agnostic absolutely should use `shared_ptr<T>`.

This code you gave is invalid, because it causes deletion of an object with static lifetime.

```
static SomeType st;
static shared_ptr<SomeType> pt{ &st };
```

This is just fine:

```
static SomeType st;
static shared_ptr<SomeType> pt{ std::shared_ptr<SomeType>{}, &st };
```

and that `pt` can be used interchangeably with "normal" shared_ptr instances.  `std::shared_ptr` is particularly convenient in this regard, because the presence or absence of a deleter doesn't affect the pointer type (in contrast, `std::unique_ptr<T, custom_deleter<T>>` is a different type from `std::unique_ptr<T, default_deleter<T>>`)

This and other ways to specify a deleter that doesn't do anything are described at:

- [How do you make std::shared_ptr not call delete()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20131877/103167)