# C++ sharing one variable among more instances of object

Tags: c++, object, struct, object-lifetime

Is there any way how can I share one variable (object of class) over more instances of another class? Static member is not what I am looking for. I know that one variable (large object) will be shared among more instances (but not all of them). How can I do that in C++? Thanks for any help.

Example:

```
class ClassA {
public:
   ...
private:
   ClassB object; // this variable will be shared among more instances of ClassA
}
```

Comment: You can store a pointer to an object. Instead of having `ClassB object` you'd have `ClassB *object`.

Comment: Best would be to use a `std::shared_pointer`, to avoid problems of knowing when to delete it.

Comment: What do you mean by "more instances" ?

Comment: @Barmar How do you know it needs to be deleted?

Comment: @NeilButterworth If it's shared dynamically it probably needs to be created dynamically, and then most likely needs to be deleted when all those objects go away.

Comment: @Barmar Equally likely, it's a static object of some sort shared by a normal pointer or reference (note I know the member is not static).

Comment: @NeilButterworth Possible, true. *Equally* likely, I suspect not.

Comment: @NeilButterworth `shared_ptr` will work with pointers to static, too? So little harm.

Comment: @Barmar How would a shared_ptr to a statically allocated object work?

Comment: @NeilButterworth https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41751514/are-shared-ptr-on-static-objects-good

Comment: @Barmar The upvoted answer there says "It is incorrect to use shared_ptr to manage static objects" . Obviously, you can have a shared_ptr with a do-nothing deleter, but then you basically have an ordinary pointer, so why would you do that?

Comment: @Barmar It's almost always a design error to have a `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr` or any owning smart ptr to an object that is not actually owned.

Comment: "_one variable (large object) will be shared among more instances_" shared by which ones? please describe its lifetime; who is responsible to construct it; etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you'll need to move the member out of the class, and store a pointer instead. You'll also need to count the instances that refer to that independent object. That's a lot of work, but fortunately the C++ standard library has you covered with `std::shared_ptr`:

```
class ClassA {
public:
   // ...
private:
   std::shared_ptr<ClassB> object; // this variable will be shared among more instances of ClassA
};
```

Comment: And what if I know that this ClassB object won't change and I will just read from it? Does it help somehow?

Comment: @P.N. - Well, you may then hold a `shared_ptr<const ClassB>`. Which is even sounder. But a shared pointer you will need to hold nontheless.

Comment: The `object` variable is not shared - the thing it points to might be. And how does the `object` variable get initialised or assigned? I think this is  a pretty poor answer to the OP's question. And see my comments above on whether a shared pointer is at all appropriate here..

Answer (score 0):

You could use pointers.

```
class B { ... }

class A {
    ...
    B *b;
    ...
}

main() {
    A a1, a2;
    B *b1 = new B();

    a1.b = b1;
    a2.b = b1;
}
```

That way `b` member on both `a1` and `a2` reference the same object.

Comment: Didn't know about std::shared_ptr. And as @StoryTeller states in his answer, it would be quite a pain in the a*s to keep track of which objects reference the same object and also to know when to delete said referenced object.

Comment: don't forget about how you would delete it when done.  especially if this is done in different scopes.

Comment: That's the point of `shared_ptr` -- when the last reference to the shared pointer is deleted, the object it points to is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I think std::shared_ptr might be what you want.
In that case your code would be something like that:

```
class ClassA {

public:
   ...
private:
   std::shared_ptr<ClassB> object; // this variable will be shared among more  instances of ClassA
}
```

But you will need to define where that pointer is instantiated, that depends on your needs. Maybe you could provide more context to your question like:

- Where does ObjectB come from, is it owned by another entity?
- How is it distributed to the instances of ObjectA?

Answer (score 0):

use static variable:

```
class ClassA {
public:

   ...
private:
   static ClassB *object; // this variable will be shared among more instances of 
}

ClassB * ClassA::object = nullptr;

ClassA::ClassA()
{
   if (object == nullptr)
      object = new ClassB();
}
```