# How to use shared_ptr to manage already ref-count managed objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory

if an object is already reference-counted (like glib in C), having `obj_ref`, `obj_unref`. All we have is a pointer like `obj *p`.

How can we use c++'s `shared_ptr` to manage the object so that we can have an uniform interface.

---

Ok, it seems that a lot of people have misunderstood my intension.

The greatest issue here is not about deleter. It's about inform of the original manager that I increased the refcount.

If I assigned or copied, only `std::shared_ptr` increased the refcount, but the original one did not. Is there anyway to inform it? So as the unref operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make std::shared\_ptr not call delete()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131877/how-do-you-make-stdshared-ptr-not-call-delete)

Comment: Not possible, this is the reason why boost::intrusive_ptr exists.

Comment: @n.m. Also note there's a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0468r0.html) to add retain_ptr to the standard library which supreseeds boost::intrusive_ptr:h

Answer (score 3):

`std::shared_ptr` allows you to pass a custom deleter which is called when the owned object should be destroyed. You could use it to call `obj_unref`.

```
obj* p = create_obj();
p->obj_ref();
std::shared_ptr<obj> sp(p, [](auto p) {
        p->obj_unref();
    });
/* use sp normally, obj will be 'obj_unref'ed and deleted when sp goes out of scope */
```

I don't know how a `obj` is created and if it gets destroyed by `obj_unref()` when the count reaches 0, but I hope you see what I mean.
The idea is to increment `obj`s internal reference count just once at the beginning, and decrement it just once when the last `shared_ptr` is destroyed.

Comment: How does this solution *increment* the ref count when the shared_ptr is copied?

Comment: It doesn't. The idea is to increment the internal `obj` ref cout just once at the beginning, and decrement it just once when the last `shared_ptr` is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to somehow duct tape `std::shared_ptr`'s refcounting to your custom one, that won't end well. Just write a custom pointer:

```
struct objPtr {

    objPtr()
    : _ptr{nullptr} { }

    objPtr(obj *ptr)
    : _ptr{ptr} {
        if(_ptr)
            _ptr->obj_ref();
    }

    ~objPtr() {
        if(_ptr)
            _ptr->obj_unref();
    }

    objPtr(objPtr const &orig)
    : objPtr{orig._ptr} { }

    objPtr &operator = (objPtr const &orig) {
        obj *const oPtr = std::exchange(_ptr, orig._ptr);

        _ptr->obj_ref();
        oPtr->obj_unref();

        return *this;
    }

    obj &operator * () { return *_ptr; }
    obj const &operator * () const { return *_ptr; }

    obj *operator -> () { return _ptr; }
    obj const *operator -> () const { return _ptr; }

    operator bool() const { return _ptr; }
    bool operator ! () const { return !_ptr; }

private:
    obj *_ptr;
};
```

Add move construction and assignment if you so wish.

Answer (score 1):

When you want a `shared_ptr`, start with a `unique_ptr`.  Then build up.

```
struct cleanup_obj {
  // not called with nullptr:
  void operator()(obj* t)const {
    obj_unref(t);
  }
};
using obj_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, cleanup_obj>;
using obj_shared_ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;
template<class T>
obj_unique_ptr<T> make_unique_refcount( T* t ) {
  using ptr=obj_unique_ptr<T>;
  if (!t) return ptr();
  obj_ref(t);
  return ptr(t);
}
template<class T>
obj_shared_ptr<T> make_shared_refcount( T* t ) {
  return make_unique_refcount(t); // implicit convert does right thing
}
```

What did I do?

First, I wrote a `unique_ptr` wrapper, because we may as well be complete, and it solves the `shared_ptr` case via the unique_ptr->shared_ptr implicit conversion.

For `unique_ptr`, we have to say we aren't using the default object destroyer.  In this case, we are using a stateless function object that knows how to `obj_unref` an `obj*`.  The stateless function object keeps the overhead at zero.

For the null case, we don't first add a reference, as that is rude.

For `shared_ptr`, the fact that we have a working `unique_ptr` makes it a free function.  `shared_ptr` will happily store the destroyer function that `unique_ptr` has.  It doesn't have to be told it has a special object destroyer, because `shared_ptr` type erases object destruction by default.  (This is because `unique_ptr<T>` is zero-overhead over a naked pointer, while `shared_ptr<T>` has unavoidable overhead of the reference counting block; the designers figured once you have that reference counting block, adding in a type-erased destruction function was not really expensive).

Note that our `obj_unique_ptr<T>` is also zero overhead over a naked pointer.  Quite often you'll want one of these instead of the shared one.

---

Now, you can upgrade the `obj_unique_ptr` to a full on intrusive pointer, with less overhead than a `shared_ptr`, if you want.

```
 template<class T>
 struct obj_refcount_ptr : obj_unique_ptr<T> // public
 {
   // from unique ptr:
   obj_refcount_ptr(obj_unique_ptr<T> p):obj_unique_ptr<T>(std::move(p)){}
   obj_refcount_ptr& operator=(obj_unique_ptr<T> p){
     static_cast<obj_unique_ptr<T>&>(*this)=std::move(p);
     return *this;
   }

   obj_refcount_ptr(obj_refcount_ptr&&)=default;
   obj_refcount_ptr& operator=(obj_refcount_ptr&&)=default;
   obj_refcount_ptr()=default;

   obj_refcount_ptr(obj_refcount_ptr const& o):
     obj_refcount_ptr(make_unique_refcount(o.get())
   {}
   obj_refcount_ptr& operator=(obj_refcount_ptr const& o) {
     *this = make_unique_refcount(o.get());
     return *this;
   }
 };
```

which I think covers it.  Now it is a zero-overhead reference counting intrusive smart pointer.  These intrusive smart pointers can be converted toa `std::shared_ptr<T>` via implicit conversion, as they are still `unique_ptr`s.  They are just `unique_ptr`s we have taught to copy themselves!

It does require moving from an `obj_refcount_ptr` to get a `shared_ptr`.  We can fix this:

```
operator std::shared_ptr<T>() const {
  return obj_refcount_ptr(*this);
}
```

which creatres an `obj_refcount_ptr` copy of `*this` and moves it into the `shared_ptr`.  Only one add ref is called, and the remove ref is only called when the `shared_ptr` count goes to zero.

---

The general approach is to start with the simplest smart pointer (`unique_ptr`), get it right, then exploit its implementation to get us the `shared_ptr` and eventually the `refcount_ptr`.  We can test the `unique_ptr` implementation in isolation, and its correctness makes testing the richer pointers easier.

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest approach, the least invasive one with the minimal possibility of breaking something, is to simply write your own facade for the object, with the underlying object as a private member and providing simple wrappers to access it.

Then use a `std::shared_ptr` to that.

Answer (score -1):

It's an incredibly bad idea to have the same objects in multiple smart pointer implementations as their ref counts can't know about each other. As soon as the ref count hits zero in one it will delete the object even if the other still holds refs.

If you really had to you could construct your smart pointers with custom deleters (that do nothing), but I really wouldn't recommend this approach.

Pick one implementation and stick to it.

Comment: If your pointer abstraction calls obj_ref on retain and obj_unref on release, you can be sure you are not violating the original semantics of ref counting..