# Is it safe to read stdin/cin from an ifstream?

Tags: c++, stdin, ifstream, cin, istream

I've read that it's possible to read cin via an ifstream by changing the buffer, but is it safe? What are the disadvantages to doing it this way:

`file.ios::rdbuf(cin.rdbuf());`

Thanks

[C++: UNIX - defaulting ifstream variable to standard input](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1448313)
[iostream - C++: assign cin to an ifstream variable? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159452/c-assign-cin-to-an-ifstream-variable)

Comment: Don't bother me (or others here) following links! Extract **your** concerns and show them here!!

Comment: Ok I'll edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe, that is the entire reason that the `rdbuf` functions exist.

It's also one of the major reasons that iostreams are dog slow.  An `ifstream` object isn't necessarily attached to a file.  A `stringstream` object might be attached to a file.  Lots of polymorphism, lots of virtual calls, no chance for optimization.

But you pay for those disadvantages whether you rebind streams or not.

Comment: My original example was wrong, can you look over the edit? I have some code that uses an ifstream and I wanted to pass cin instead. I'm thinking of `file.ios::rdbuf(cin.rdbuf());` but I don't know if that's ok. As long as the code doesn't call open or close on file is it ok?

Comment: Disagree with sentiment. The virtual calls in `rdbuf` are not going to slow down File I/O, and formatted I/O isn't that fast either. If you're doing unformatted I/O, you can directly call the `streambuf` methods skipping the abstraction cost too.

Comment: MSalters, disagree all you want, I have profiler data forming the basis of my statements. Note that the calls I'm talking about are not in rdbuf. However rdbuf cannot exist without the polymorphic pimpl machinery.

Comment: @Ben If you could respond to my original comment, so that I can mark this answer you gave correct if it is so. Thanks

Comment: @test: your edit didn't require any change to the answer. You can associate a file with cin and the reverse also works.