# Store pointer to istream and ostream in a class C++

Tags: c++

game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "piece.h"

using namespace std;

class Game
{
    private:
        string white;
        string black;
        string title;
        istream* in;
        ostream* out;
    public:
        Game();
        Game(istream&, ostream&);
        void display(Colour, short);
};

#endif
```

game.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "game.h"
#include "board.h"
#include "piece.h"

using namespace std;

Game::Game()
{
    //nothing
}

Game::Game(istream& is, ostream& os)
{
    in = is;
    out = os;
}

void Game::display(Colour colour, short moves)
{
    //out << "a";
}
```

I'm trying to use the istream and ostream in other parts of my class but I can't because g++ won't let me reference is to in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply want a reference variable, not a pointer.

```
class Game
{
    private:
        ...
        istream& in;
        ostream& out;
    public:
        Game(istream&, ostream&);
};

Game::Game(istream& is, ostream& os)
    : in( is ),
      out( os )
    { }
```

The existing code compiles because of a couple language quirks:

- `istream` / `ostream` are convrtible to `void*` to allow you to check their error status as in

  ```
    if( in ) { do_something( in ); }
  ```
- your compiler apparently allowed `void*` to be converted to `ostream*` (I believe in error, and you should at least get a warning from this).

Comment: I also used help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366955/obtain-a-stdostream-either-from-stdcout-or-stdofstreamfile/366969#366969

Answer (score 4):

You should deference the pointer:

```
*out << "a";
```

For more convenient use, to not deference the pointers each time, and for more readability you can use references instead of pointers.

```
class Game
{
    // ...
    std::istream& in;    // notice explicit namespace std::
    std::ostream& out;
    // ...
};
```

Then you can write:

```
out << "a";
```

Plus, it is not a good habit to do so:

```
using namespace std;
```

This way you are exposing the names of std namespace.

Answer (score 2):

`is` is a reference not a pointer, therefore if you want to store a pointer you need to use the address operator `in = &is;`

But please realize that `is` can cease to exist immediately after the method call, therefore you can easily end up with an invalid pointer. Make sure that you at least document this fact.

Comment: out << "a" gives me:
game.cpp: In member function ‘void Game::display(Colour, short int)’:
game.cpp:23: error: invalid operands of types ‘std::ostream*’ and ‘const char [2]’ to binary ‘operator<<’

Comment: @Steven Because `in` IS a pointer. Therefore if you want to use the stream it is pointing to, you need to use the dereference operator `*out`

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Thanks, but now it gives a Segmentation Fault at that line.

Comment: I'm currently using cout as the ostream btw

Comment: ah, I see once that method call finishes is ceases to exist, any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

If you store pointers, you need to dereference them, like `*in` or `*out << ...`.