# How do I change a C++ output stream to refer to cout?

Tags: c++, stream, cout

I have a class that I want to give an output stream as a member to, to wit:

```
class GameBase {
protected:
    ofstream m_OutputWriter;
...
}
```

There is a method in this class that takes a string argument and opens m_OutputWriter to point to that file, so data may be output to that file by using the standard << operator;

However, what I would like is to make the stream point to cout by default, so that if the output path is not specified, output goes to the console output instead of to a file, and it will be completely transparent by the calling class, who would use

```
m_OutputWriter << data << endl;
```

to output the data to the predetermined destination.  Yet, I have tried a couple of the other examples here, and none of them exactly seem to fit what I'm trying to do.

What am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtain a std::ostream either from std::cout or std::ofstream(file)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366955/obtain-a-stdostream-either-from-stdcout-or-stdofstreamfile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to having an `std::ofstream` as a member, I would use a function that returns an `std::ostream&`.

For example:

```
class GameBase {
    std::ofstream m_OutputWriter;
protected:
    std::ostream& getOutputWriter() {
         if (m_OutputWriter)
             return m_OutputWriter;
         else
             return std::cout;
    }
    ...
}
```

A fully-functioning example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

std::ostream& get() {
    return std::cout;
}

int main() {
    get() << "Hello world!\n";
}
```

Comment: And how do I use a pointer to an output stream with the "<<" operator?  GetOutputWriter() << "Hello, World\n"; does not compile when I try it.

Comment: @Charles - And none the less, that is the correct syntax;  see the example I've attached.  You'll have to provide mre information on why it might not compile (Perhaps because it is not `const`?  You can hardly avoid that, unless you mark `m_OutputWriter` as `mutable`.).

Comment: Okay, I found the problem, I was trying something foolish because m_OutputWriter had a non-null value.  I changed the test to "if (m_OutputWriter.is_open())" and it works just fine now.  The empty parentheses drive me nuts because I do so love my properties in C#, but I guess it beats not having it work.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Why does the stream need to be a member?

```
struct GameBase {
    void out(std::ostream& out = std::cout);
    // ...
};
```