# Is it possible to execute a function every time a std::cout is used?

Tags: c++

Everytime, `std::cout` is used from the main function or other functions, I want to copy the contents of a logfile to a Fltk GUI Window.

I've implemented a function which does the copying part. I want to know if its possible to make this function run every time `std::cout` or maybe, `std::endl` is executed in the code.

How can I implement this?

EDIT:
For more clarification,

The function which needs to run every time is:

```
void printProgress(const std::string& strProgress)
{
    std::ostringstream strResultTextStream;
    strResultTextStream << m_pLogOutput->value();
    strResultTextStream << strProgress;
    m_pLogOutput->value(strResultTextStream.str().c_str());
}
```

Adding data to the output window (fl_multiline_output) requires the 4 lines of code above. Right now I have redirected the standard output messages to a log file. I wanted to run this function everytime to copy the contents of the logfile to m_pLogOutput(the Output window)

Comment: There is a difference between redirect/duplicate the "flux" of `std::cout` and have a watcher on it.

Comment: how about a wrapper?

Comment: Maybe you can use own function, which will do the copying part and then will use `std::cout`?

Comment: Sounds like it may be easier to do outside of the project. Can you run your program under an equivalent of `tee`?

Comment: Hardcoding the use of `std::cout` is bad practice anyhow. If you pass a output stream whereever you want to output something it is trivial to replace `std::cout` with some stream that does what you want.

Comment: If I wanted to redirect cout output from inside the program, I'd use rdbuf to set cout streambuf to a streambuf which does what I want.

Comment: Maybe have another thread that does blocking read from the fd associated with std::cout ?

Comment: @ formerlyknownas_463035818 @AProgrammer The thing is, the output box  (Fl_Multiline_Output) where I want to print the standard output messages requires the copying of its contents to a temporary stream, appending the new standard output message, then finally copying it back again.

Comment: @Loki - A tailored `streambuf` can do that.

Comment: I think that this example will help you : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129037/how-do-i-change-a-c-output-stream-to-refer-to-cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129037/how-do-i-change-a-c-output-stream-to-refer-to-cout)

Comment: @Peter How can I modify streambuf to run the three lines of code in the function above everytime something is placed in the cout buffer?

Answer (score -5):

I think you could use `#define` to your advantage:

```
#define cout f(parameter),cout
```

where `f()` is your function. Change `cout` with `std::cout` if you want, I don't think that will provoke errors.

Comment: this will exapnd to eg `f(),cout << "foo"` , ie it would call `f()` with no parameters. How is this supposed to help? Also replacing `cout` with a macro is calling for trouble. "I don't think that will provoke errors." I think it does

Comment: I added a parameter, are you happy now? His only real options is to replace `cout` with a macro or use `Ctrl+R` to replace `cout` with `f(parameter),cout`. He asked for the function to run **every** time `cout` is used, so a macro looks fine for me.

Comment: consider what happens when I declare a function `void foo(std::ostream& x = cout);`