# Proper way to create ostream to file or cout

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a Log class for my project at school.  It needs to either be able to write information to the stdout or to a file depending on the parameters it is passed.  I was looking into how to do this and I stumbled upon a thread with a similar question here: [Obtain a std::ostream either from std::cout or std::ofstream(file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366955/obtain-a-stdostream-either-from-stdcout-or-stdofstreamfile)

The only difference between this thread and my own is that I want to do it inside of a class.  Looking at the solution though they use `std::ostream out(buf)` and construct the ostream on the fly with buf.  How can i declare this properly in my Log class to be able to construct the "out" object only once i enter my Log constructor?

I took a quick stab at it below but I am not sure if it is correct or if I am on the right track. Appreciate any help, thanks.

EDIT: I want to be able to do `out << "Some string" << endl;` after i get this Log class working properly.

EDIT2: An error I am now receiving with the new code below `error : 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream() [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' is protected`

```
// log.h
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#ifndef LOG_H_
#define LOG_H_

class Log 
{
    public:
        enum Mode { STDOUT, FILE };

        // Needed by default
        Log(const char *file = NULL);
        ~Log();

        // Writing methods
        void write(char *);
        void write(std::string);
    private:
        Mode mode;
        std::streambuf *buf;
        std::ofstream of;
        std::ostream out;
};

#endif


// log.cpp
#include "log.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

Log::Log(const char *file)
{
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        of.open(file);
        buf = of.rdbuf();
        mode = FILE;
    }
    else
    {
        buf = std::cout.rdbuf();
        mode = STDOUT;
    }

    // Attach to out
    out.rdbuf(buf);
}

Log::~Log()
{
    if (mode == FILE)
        of.close();
}

void Log::write(std::string s)
{
    out << s << std::endl;
}

void Log::write(char *s)
{
    out << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I would add `char *file = NULL` or something similar, so that you don't have to pass any arguments in case of the `Log` to stdout. - And give your default arguments in the header file, not the implementation [you need them in any code that calls Log(), which is probably not your "log.cpp" or whatever it may be called.

Comment: Good suggestion!  Added that in.  Oh, ok i didn't remember that default arguments go in the header, not implementation.  Thanks, been a while since I have done any serious C++ programming

Comment: Other than that, the code looks about right WHat happens when you try it? [Just a thought by the way, do you really need both a "mode" and a "char *file" - why not use "char *file" to indicate whether the output should be a file or stdout - that way, you don't have to have two arguments].

Comment: Another great suggestion, damn i need to get out of the "rust" zone haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create `tmp` with `std::ostream tmp(buf);` and store the address of it in `out` with `this->out = &tmp;`. However, `tmp` will go out of scope at the end of the constructor and the pointer will no longer be pointing at a valid object.

What you should do instead is make `out` not a `std::ostream*` but simply a `std::ostream`:

```
std::ostream out;
```

Then in your constructor, once you've got the `buf` ready, you can give it to `out` by doing `out.rdbuf(buf);`.

---

Response to edit:

The `std::ostream` doesn't have a default constructor - it has to take a buffer pointer. My mistake. However, the fix is simple. Use your constructor's member initialization list to pass a null pointer (`nullptr` in C++11, `0` or `NULL` in C++03):

```
Log::Log(const char *file)
  : out(nullptr)
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i couldn't do it earlier because of the silly time limit :P  fear not.

Comment: I am having some issues compiling my new code.  I have modified my post above with the lastest version of my code and the error, can you have a quick look please?  I'm stumped. Also can't seem to get the @sftrabbit to work either :/

Comment: @PeterWood I feel like this error is a result of the code that I was provided by him...although I could be wrong.

Comment: @MasterGberry I've responded to your edit. It was my mistake.

Comment: @MasterGberry Just incase you've seen my edit already, I've edited once again with a much simpler and safer solution.

Comment: @MasterGberry I see, sorry to jump on you.