# Issues with basic_ostream

Tags: c++

I am getting this error when trying to compile my code:

```
1>  c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/ostream: In constructor 'Log::Log(const char*)':
1>c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\ostream(363,7): error : 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream() [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' is protected
1>C:\Users\Adam\Documents\cs\cs176b\hw2\ftp\ftp\log.cpp(6,26): error : within this context
```

Not really sure why, I didn't make the ostream code I am using myself, I used what was suggested here: [Proper way to create ostream to file or cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781629/proper-way-to-create-ostream-to-file-or-cout)

My code is below, happy to give any more info if needed:

```
// log.h
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#ifndef LOG_H_
#define LOG_H_

class Log 
{
    public:
        enum Mode { STDOUT, FILE };

        // Needed by default
        Log(const char *file = NULL);
        ~Log();

        // Writing methods
        void write(char *);
        void write(std::string);
    private:
        Mode mode;
        std::streambuf *buf;
        std::ofstream of;
        std::ostream out;
};

#endif


// log.cpp
#include "log.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

Log::Log(const char *file)
{
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        of.open(file);
        buf = of.rdbuf();
        mode = FILE;
    }
    else
    {
        buf = std::cout.rdbuf();
        mode = STDOUT;
    }

    // Attach to out
    out.rdbuf(buf);
}

Log::~Log()
{
    if (mode == FILE)
        of.close();
}

void Log::write(std::string s)
{
    out << s << std::endl;
}

void Log::write(char *s)
{
    out << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `std::ostream` has a protected default-constructor. You can't instantiate it like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::ostream::ostream()` constructor is protected](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/basic_ostream), which means it can only be invoked by its derived class, but not but its enclosing one.

To fix the error initialize member `out`.

The only public constructor of `std::ostream` accepts a `std::streambuf*`, e.g.:

```
Log::Log(const char *file)
    : out(std::cout.rdbuf())
// ...
```

Note, that it is safe to initialize a `std::ostream` with the buffer from `std::cout.rdbuf()`, because destructor `std::ostream::~ostream()` does not deallocate its `std::streambuf*` member.

Alternatively, it can be initialized with a `NULL`/`nullptr`. In this case be careful to not output anything into the stream as it would try dereferencing that `NULL` leading to undefined behaviour, most likely just crash with `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: Ok, so if I afterwards want to change `out` to use the file stream instead like provided in my code it will work?

Answer (score 0):

In extension to what David said:

`ostream` is just the "frame" of an output stream, a definition of basic capabilities of an output stream (abstract class). It does nothing and is not implemented.

Did you try to write to `cout` perhaps? `cout` is defined in `iostream`, you do not need to define it, just use it!