# Dereference unique_ptr to a reference

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, unique-ptr, dereference

The following (unsafe) code works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

std::ofstream* create_unsafe_stream(const char* filename) {
    return new std::ofstream {filename};
}

int main () {
    std::ofstream& u_out = *create_unsafe_stream("foo.txt");
    u_out << "foo\n" ;
    delete &u_out;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to produce a safer version

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>

using stream_ptr = std::unique_ptr<std::ostream>;

stream_ptr create_safe_stream(const char* filename) {
    return stream_ptr{ new std::ofstream {filename}};
}

int main() {
  std::ostream& s_out = *create_safe_stream("foo.txt");
  s_out << "foo\n" << std::endl; 
  return 0
}
```

Which compiles but, when I run it give me a segmentation fault. I was thinking that the problem is caused by the `unique_ptr` going out of the scope. So I tried to modify a bit the `main` to

```
int main() {
   stream_ptr ofile = create_safe_stream("foo.txt");
   std::ostream& s_out = *ofile;
   s_out << "foo\n"; 
}
```

which works again.

## QUESTION

Is there a way not to use an 'intermediate' variable like `ofile` and doing all in a line?

## EDIT

The function `create_safe_stream` is a toy model of [what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521318/ostream-class-that-outputs-either-on-cout-or-on-a-file), that is this function may return either the `std::ofstream` to that file or the `std::cout`, so I think I really need to return a pointer to the base class `std::ostream`. How can I do?

Comment: (After the edit):  `ofile` is not intermediate, it's the OWNER of the object.  Rather `s_out` is a helper alias to the contained object.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is correct. `create_safe_stream` returns a `std::unique_ptr` which immediately goes out of scope and thus the raw resource it holds is `deleted` and trying to use it is UB.

The way to not use an intermediate variable and doing it all in one line is by just returning a `std::ofstream` object instead:

```
std::ofstream create_safe_stream(const char* filename) {
    return std::ofstream {filename};
}

int main() {
  std::ostream s_out = create_safe_stream("foo.txt");
  s_out << "foo\n" << std::endl; 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However what I wrote was a 'toy model' of my problem. Actually the function `create_safe_stream` should either open a file or redirect `std::out` (as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521318/ostream-class-that-outputs-either-on-cout-or-on-a-file), therefore I think that I really need to return a pointer to `std::ostream`. Is there a way to do it anyhow?

Comment: You’d still have to hold onto the smart pointer, but one trick you can do in that case is return a `std::unique_ptr<std::osteram, std::function<void(std::ostream*)>>` where you either have the deleted be `[](std::ostream* os) { delete os; }` or if you are returning a pointer to `std::cout`, the deleter is a nop. (For optimal performance, don’t use `std::function`, but hopefully you get the idea.)