# How to switch between std::ofstream and std::cerr

Tags: c++, stl

I would like to write a function that returns an ostream that either writes to a file or stderr.

My first attempt:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

std::ostream get_stream() {
    bool flag = (time(nullptr) % 2); // stand-in
    if (flag)
        return std::cerr;
    else
        return std::ofstream{"somefile.txt"};
}

int main() {
    auto logger {get_stream()};
    logger << "Just testing, everything is fine."
           << std::endl;
}
```

This fails with a (long) compiler error - I suspect because `std::cerr` does not have a copy constructor. Another variant (returning a reference) does not work because the `ofstream` is a local variable. I could allocate the `ofstream` on the heap, but then the caller doesn't know if the pointer needs to be freed (it doesn't when we return a reference to `std:cerr`).

So, I wrote version 2:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

struct Logger {
    std::ofstream ostream;
    bool to_stderr {true};

    template<typename A>
    Logger& operator<<(A rhs) {
        if (to_stderr)
            std::cerr << rhs;
        else
            ostream << rhs;
        return this;
    }
};

int main() {
    Logger logger;
    logger << "Just testing, everything is fine."
           << std::endl;
}
```

This also fails with a long compile error that starts with:

```
$ g++ -Wall -o v2 v2.cpp
v2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
v2.cpp:30:12: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘Logger’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’)
     logger << "Just testing, everything is fine."
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            << std::endl;
            ^~~~~~
v2.cpp:9:13: note: candidate: template<class A> Logger& Logger::operator<<(A)
     Logger& operator<<(A rhs) {
             ^~~~~~~~
v2.cpp:9:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
v2.cpp:30:20: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘A’
            << std::endl;
                    ^~~~
[...]
```

Why isn't the second version working, and what is the right way to implement something like this?

([Using << operator to write to both a file and cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413744) is a related question, but as far as I can tell the only difference in the solution given there is that `operator<<` is defined outside the class, and if I make the same change to my code, I'm still getting the same error)

Comment: You can't pass or return streams by value.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56521318/5754656

Comment: The first one will work if `get_stream()` returns `std::ostream&`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Returning a reference fixes the case where we want to return `cerr`, but it breaks returning the file stream because that is a local variable.

Comment: @Nikratio — so don’t make it a local variable.

Comment: @PeteBecker If I allocate it on the heap, the caller doesn't know if the pointer needs to be freed or not. If I make it global, I can only have one active stream at any time (which works in the example, but not in general)

Comment: @Nikratio -- I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. You've accepted an answer that explains how to do what you're objecting to here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to dynamically-allocate your streams:

```c++
std::unique_ptr<std::ostream> get_stream() {
  bool flag = time(0) % 2;
  return ( flag
    ? std::make_unique<std::ostream>(std::cerr.rdbuf())
    : std::make_unique<std::ofstream>("somefile.txt")
  );
}

int main() {
  auto logger {get_stream()};
  *logger << "Just testing, everything is fine."
          << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising, thanks! I think the real trick here is not to dynamically allocate, but to construct a new stream for `std:cerr` using `cerr.rdbuf`. Could you say a few more works about this? Is this always safe? Will writes to `std:cerr` and the "other" `cerr` be synchronized correctly?

Comment: @Nikratio No, they will not be synchronized (if I understand your meaning of the word synchronized). `std::cerr` is by default tied to `std::cout` so any output operation on `std::cerr` will flush `std::cout`, keeping them synchronized. This is not the case with the returned stream in this example. If you want a complete copy of `std::cerr` you would use `copyfmt` after calling the constructor. `? []{auto o=std::make_unique<std::ostream>(std::cerr.rdbuf());o->copyfmt(std::cerr);return o;}()`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to elevate the file stream to global status. This could be a global variable, a static member, or (my favorite) a block-local static variable. This approach ensures the file stream won't be opened until its first invocation, and will stay open until program termination.

From there you just return the stream by reference.

```cpp
std::ostream &get_stream() {
    static std::ofstream file("somefile.txt");
    return flag ? std::cerr : file;
}
```

Comment: Also note that in `main()`, the logger would need to be defined as a reference: `auto& logger` or `decltype(auto) logger`.

Comment: Elevating this to a global variable is only possible because the example is deliberately simple. In the actual code, the file name varies and multiple streams may be in use at the same time.